# getComputedStyle and transitions

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-transitions

Looking for a workaround while I consider submitting a bug to Chromium -

If an element has a transition, `getComputedStyle` does not return what you would expect it to return until after the transition is over.

Long and short - if I have an element with a height of 24px, and adding a class gives it a height of 80px (with a transition to and from), and both heights are defined in the stylesheet - if I set that class and check `getComputedStyle`, it still gives me the non-class height until the transition has ended.

A sample of what I'm talking about here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #foo {
                display: inline-block;
                background-color: red;
                height: 24px;
                padding: 4px 0;
                width: 200px;
                -webkit-transition-property: height;
                -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
                -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms;
            }
            #foo.changed {
                height: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="foo"></div>
        <p>before: <span id="before"></span></p>
        <p>after: <span id="after"></span></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">   
            var foo 
            function checkFoo(e) {
                foo.classList.toggle('changed');
                document.getElementById('before').innerText = window.getComputedStyle(foo, null).getPropertyValue("height");
            };

            window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                foo = document.getElementById('foo');

                foo.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd', function(e){
                document.getElementById('after').innerText = window.getComputedStyle(foo, null).getPropertyValue("height");
                });
    
                foo.addEventListener('click', checkFoo, false);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle of this sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/bobbudd/REeBN/

(Note: This fiddle is only going to work in webkit, it's the one browser we're targeting believe it or not -- but I've also tested and get the same issue in Firefox)

Problem is, I have multiple cases where I need to know the final style (some might say the "computed" style) BEFORE the `transitionEnd` happens.

Or I guess it's part of a larger question - with so many different ways to know they height of an element as it is at a specific moment in time, should `getComputedStyle` not get what the stylesheet (or style attribute) says the property is supposed to be?

And before you ask if I can put the final number in the JS, the answer is (unfortunately) no.

Can anybody think of a way of getting this final value before the transition ends?

Comment: I do not understand the question quite clearly. What i get out of it is that you want some values before the element is actually triggered?

Comment: no - the element has already been triggered, so I expect the new value (80px), but it doesn't give me that new value until the transition is over. I need a way to get it as soon as the trigger has happened, but before the transition is ended.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug at all. `getComputedStyle` is meant to return the client rendered value of an attribute at the time you invoke it. If you invoke it during the transition you will get the value during the transition, as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/REeBN/1/

The way you can get the final values as set by a rule is by examining the rule itself, probably through the use of `cssRules`.

Here is an implementation using `window.getMatchedCSSRules`:

```
cssRules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(this);
var finalCssRule = "";
for(var i = 0; i < cssRules.length; i++){
    if(cssRules[i].selectorText == "#foo.changed"){
        finalCssRule = cssRules[i];
    }
}
document.getElementById('final').innerText = finalCssRule.cssText;
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/REeBN/2/

Comment: This is what I was worried about. This is for an app framework, so getting the cssRules for a specific app may prove longer of a process than is worth it. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @el_bob I've added an example of how you can retrieve the appropriate rule as well.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that - thanks. Since we're only building the framework and not the apps, it loks like we'll have to score all `getMatchedCSSRule` selectors to see which one we're going to use. Again, I had considered this and threw it away as not optimal. Would be nice to have a way of telling directly what element _A_ is supposed to look like with its current selectors without having to parse through any information.

Comment: @el_bob A workaround could be to not have the transition initially. Apply the class and find the height (which will change instantaneously), then remove it. Next, apply a class that has the transition rules and reapply the original class. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does, and unfortunately I had considered your approach before and it's what I feared I would have to do - but I'm not jazzed about having to hack around something. I just wish there were a more direct route.